# Hide scrollbar in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I have a scrollable DIV with `overflow: scroll`. This works perfect in nearly all browsers except in Chrome for Android where it shows the scrollbars. I don't know if this is a bug or what. Does anyone have a solution for this?

The following browsers don't show the scrollbars:

1) Macbook Pro Chrome

2) iOS Chrome

3) Native Samsung Galaxy browser

Only Chrome on any Android device would show the scrollbars.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by simple replacing `overflow: scroll` with `overflow: auto;` which would still allow the div to be scrollable without showing the scrollbars in Chrome for Android

Thanks